# mobile browsers bypassing elseif statements but working fine on desktop and local host

Tags: php, if-statement, mobile

I have a very simple set of elseif statements to redirect users using header after confirming password / username correct. It works perfectly well on localhost and all desktop browsers as expected. (tom goes to admin page if toms password is correct / other correct passwords go to their assigned page)

However, when run on mobile mobile devices it skips to the else statement. (tom goes to home page (WRONG PAGE) if toms password is correct / other correct passwords go to home page NOT the page they are assigned)

I have tried changing all statements to if instead of elseif (as explained in another stack overflow question)

caveat: I realize that this isn't secure and intend to include prepared statements / password hashing for security. But, I need to figure this out before I can continue.

I have spent hours trying to figure out why and have tried numerous variations. I'm hoping it's something simple that I just can't see.

I am new to using PHP so please be gentle if this seems really obvious. I have killed many hours trying to figure this out through this website and others and I am also trying to learn as much as I can as i go along.

Thanks in advance.....

```
<?php

session_start();


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

//error handlers

//check for empty fields

if (empty($name) || empty($pwd) ){

   header("Location: ../index.php?entry=empty");
   exit();

} else {

    // check if input characters are valid

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $name) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $pwd))  {

        header("Location: ../index.php?entry=invalid-entry");
        exit();

    } else {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$name' AND user_pwd='$pwd'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($resultCheck < 1) {

            header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
            exit();

        } else {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $_SESSION['u_name'] = $row['user_name'];
                $_SESSION['u_pwd'] = $row['user_pwd'];

                if ($name == 'tom') {
                    header("Location: ../admin.php?login=success");
                    exit;

                } elseif ($name == 'dick') {
                    header("Location: ../page_one.php?login=success");
                    exit;    

                } elseif ($name == 'harry') {
                    header("Location: ../page_two.php?login=success");
                    exit;

                } elseif ($name == 'joe') {
                    header("Location: ../page_three.php?login=success");
                    exit;

                } elseif ($name == 'bloggs') {
                    header("Location: ../page_four.php?login=success");
                    exit;

                } else {
                    header("Location: ../HOME.php?login=success");
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }            
    }
}

} else {
header("Location: ../index.php");
exit();
}
```

Comment: Are you properly submitting your form when testing your website with a mobile browser (probably the form is not submitted, thus your first if-check fails and you end up on the homepage)? As your php code runs server-side it should not matter who is calling it.

Comment: Yes, my form is working as it should. It was in fact the case sensitive element that i didn't account for. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this has anything to do with the mobile browser, since the PHP script is executed on the server.

On the other hand, when you type something on most mobile devices, the first letter is capital by default and your checks are case sensitive. Are you sure that you write 'tom' and not 'Tom' on mobile?

Comment: I knew it would be something ridiculous!! ....unbelievable that i didn't check that! I did however learn a great deal trying to find out what was wrong haha. Thank you so much..it sometimes just takes another pair of eyes to confirm the obvious. I would have saved myself several hours as well. Have a great day Ivan...really appreciated.